# Case or if statement in SSIS expression

Tags: sql-server, parameters, ssis, expression, ssis-2012

I have a project parameter in SSIS that I want to use to be able to change our data source connections.

I'm trying to write an expression in the connection properties but I'm coming up short. I want to be able to evaluate a few different values and return different values if true

Here's what I have

```
@[$Project::Parameter] == "SERVER1" ? @[$Project::SERVER1_ConnectionString]  
: ( @[$Project::Parameter] == "SERVER2" ? @[$Project::SERVER2_ConnectionString] 
: ( @[$Project::Parameter] == "SERVER3" ? @[$Project::SERVER3_ConnectionString]  
: "Unknown Server"))
```

I've tried adding in other servers to this code and I must not be understanding how you can evaluate additional results and set additional values

Basically, I'm looking to do this

If `Parameter = SERVER1` then give me `SERVER1_ConnectionString`, if `Parameter = SERVER2`, then give me `SERVER2_ConnectionString` and so on...

**EDIT: The syntax was correct but my issue was having a typo my project parameter**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Evaluate variable as Expression**

The easiest way is to Add a Variable `@[User::ConnectionSting]` of type String, Select to Evaluate this variable as expression, and use the following expression:

```
@[$Project::Parameter] == "SERVER1" ? @[$Project::SERVER1_ConnectionString]  
: ( @[$Project::Parameter] == "SERVER2" ? @[$Project::SERVER2_ConnectionString] 
: ( @[$Project::Parameter] == "SERVER3" ? @[$Project::SERVER3_ConnectionString]  
: ""))
```

Then Click on the OLEDB Connection Manager, press <kbd>F4</kbd> to Show the properties Tab, GoTo Expression, Select the ConnectionString property and use the following expression:

```
@[User::ConnectionSting]
```

And Click on the data flow task and the tasks that uses the connection and Set the `Delay Validation` property to `True`

**Using Expression Task**

You can use the same method but instead of evaluating `@[User::ConnectionSting]` as expression, add an Expression Task at the package beginning and use the following expression:

```
@[User::ConnectionSting] = (@[$Project::Parameter] == "SERVER1" ? 
@[$Project::SERVER1_ConnectionString] : ( @[$Project::Parameter] == "SERVER2" ? @[$Project::SERVER2_ConnectionString] : ( @[$Project::Parameter] == "SERVER3" ? @[$Project::SERVER3_ConnectionString] : "")))
```

Comment: Hadi, I'm going to give you the answer because the issue was that I had a parameter named wrong. Always seems something simple holds me up :)